# Problem in VSCode when updating Angular Services to version 16 roando project in version 8

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, plugins

When updating the Angular Language Service plugin to version 16, some imports started showing an error in VSCode:

```
This likely means that the library (@angular/common) which declares CommonModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

The solution found, until I found time to migrate everything to Angular 16, was to reduce the plugin to version 15.2.1. Thus, VSCode no longer reported the error.

I was wondering if there is any workaround, or if it's just a temporary bug and will be fixed in a next version of Angular Language Service. Or if the best solution would be to migrate the application to version 16 of angular.